# windows not booting due to grub4dos

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub

I am a high school student and was installing Linux for study related stuffs along with windows. When installed it was not showing option to boot so i fixed with EasyBCD in which added a new boot option, which activated grub4dos. It shows these 2 screens in the pic after which i reinstalled linux, using the previous pendrive. After which i tried the following troubleshooting which i thought will help but it didn't.

I tried booting from bootable pendrive, using safe mode and downloaded windows from official windows server (2004 version). However etcher shows 'missing partition' or something (see pic) so this option is not available.

I thought unstalling EasyBCD would work, so i installed WINE, but it was of no help, as after unstalling it showed similar screen. I also tried to uncheck linux option from there but it did't work.

The last option i can figure out is to delete the File or Folder which contain the grub4dos, but i can't figure out where it is. How can I delete windows files from Linux (I am using Linux Lite) (I am farely new so please pardon me if i don't understand something).

Thanks for your help

https://ibb.co/51GrM3G (grub4dos) https://ibb.co/9wJ4xdr (grub4dos) https://ibb.co/98C88Lm (etcher)

Comment: Is Windows installed in UEFI boot mode. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning since 2012. So most hardware now is UEFI. But users can install in now 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. EasyBCD with very old grub4dos only boots with old BIOS systems. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: thanks oldfred for your help will try your solution but my laptop(HP) is from 2011 and i dont remember updating bios so i see very less option and features in BIOS.  thanks again also it would be great help if you rewrite the solution with more layman terms

Comment: If from 2011, it probably is BIOS and had Windows 7 in BIOS boot mode. So is then your Windows an upgrade from Windows 7? A few that booted Windows most of the time have used EasyBCD and the old grub4dos. You have to install grub2 from your Ubuntu install into the PBR, partition boot sector of the Linux install. Grub2 recommended you do not do that as it does not really fit in a PBR and has to hard code things making it more fragile. Never install grub2 boot loader to PBR of any Windows partition, as that breaks Windows.

Comment: yes its an upgrade. , although i dint knew what easyBCD was still i used and got struck(proabbly didnt knew it can do that)

Comment: We normally suggest dual boot with grub2 managing boot. But Windows 10 also has made that more difficult. Grub only boots working Windows. And Windows 10 keeps turning fast start up back on. If user on has one drive, or one place for boot loader and Windows breaks or adds fast start up, then you have to temporarily install Windows boot loader, fix Windows, then restore grub. Or a bit of a hassle. So if mostly Windows, perhaps EasyBCD. But if mostly Ubuntu, better to have grub in MBR. Either way have Ubuntu live installer & Windows repair flash drive always handy. UEFI is like multiple MBR.

Comment: i understand but the problem i am facing is that i cant make a working bootable pendrive even

Answer (score 0):

Hey there Nitin looks like your grub4dos can't find the mbr. I think you are completely mixing bootloaders, either use grub4dos or easybcd not bot. As well Wine is windows emulation for Linux. (Don't need it for now).
Your easiest option is get windows 10 and use LSW.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Or reinatall windows then install Linux follow these directions.

https://itsfoss.com/guide-install-linux-mint-16-dual-boot-windows/

Comment: EasyBCD is not a bootloader, it's a utility to configure Windows' (MBR/VBR) bootloader.

Comment: I'm also not so sure that using WSL on Windows 10/Server 2019 is going to be a viable option. They've mentioned Windows Server 2004 (probably meant 2003) and also considering that they're using grub4dos (which I've never even heard of), it sounds like the computer could be pretty old.

Comment: My second comment is (probably) wrong. He probably meant the 20.04 version of Server 2019

Comment: I was just looking for the easiest way for him to use LInux. I personally hate dual boot, I only use Windows in a VM under linux.

Comment: hi mark and oskar , thanks for your reply actually my laptop was not working but i needed it  for my classes that why i wanted to install linux (but the problem was in power brick so it dosent matter for now). it was no showing linux as an option at first thats why i used easyBCD and ticked linux there, probably the windows will work simply if i start CMD and repair boot in safe mode but here is the problem i cannot figure out how to make a bootable pendrive since  etcher is giving error and unnetbootin also not working. if you could help me out here it would be a great help.Thanks again